# In MySQL, combine a query to get column name with a second query on that column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use field name to determine the column that I will use to search for, but first I have to use the name to look up a column ID, then concatenate the column ID with a string to get the actual column name. I'm doing with with two queries now, but I'd like to combine them into a single query.

For example, I want to search for "fool=true". In the first table, I find out that values for "fool" are in column 1 of the second table. In the second table, I do the *real* search, for "field_id_1=true".

This table maps names to column IDs used in the second table.

```
exp_channel_fields
+field_id +field_name +
|---------|-----------|
|1        |fool       |
|2        |money      |
+---------+-----------|
```

This table has the data I want to search, but the column names don't quite match the ID from the prior step. I have to prepend "field_id_" to the ID I found before:

```
exp_channel_data
+entry_id+field_id_1 +field_id_2 +
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|837     |true       |$500       |
|838     |false      |$50,000    |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here's the first query I use, and I store the result into $myFieldID.

```
SELECT field_id as tField_id FROM exp_channel_fields 
WHERE field_name = 'fool'
```

Then I use the result to build the second query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id ORDER BY entry_id SEPARATOR '|')
    AS result_entries
FROM exp_channel_data
WHERE field_id_{$myFieldID} = "true"
```

Is there a way to combine these into a single query? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think it is not possible to do so:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985842/mysql-concat-to-create-column-names

Comment: I'll look into server prepared statements. That would at least eliminate the PHP code I'm using now to use the values returned from one query to construct the second query.

Comment: @phoet, Your comment was the most helpful answer. One, it's not possible to directly do what I asked. Two, the link to server prepared statements *almost* provided the workaround I needed. (Alas, ExpressionEngine blocks server prepared statements.) Would you like to repost your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to use query-results as column names, but you can use server-side prepared statements to achieve a similar behavior. have a look at this question:

[MySQL concat() to create column names to be used in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985842/mysql-concat-to-create-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

Your database is not right normalized. You should unpivot columns to rows in order to make this kind of querys:

```
exp_channel_fields
+field_id +field_name +
|---------|-----------|
|1        |fool       |
|2        |money      |
+---------+-----------|


exp_channel_data
+entry_id+field_id + value
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|837     |1          |true       |
|837     |2          |$500       |
|838     |1          |False      |
|838     |2          |$50,000    |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Then the query is really easy:

SELECT field_id as tField_id FROM exp_channel_fields 
WHERE field_name = 'fool'

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id ORDER BY entry_id SEPARATOR '|')
    AS result_entries
FROM 
   exp_channel_data inner join 
   exp_channel_fields 
     on exp_channel_data.field_id = exp_channel_data.field_id
WHERE value = "true"
```

Perhaps you will need table-base and sub-tables for exp_channel_fields because differents value types.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the tables. This is the way they're laid out in ExpressionEngine CMS. Thanks, though for the example. I'll keep it in mind for future projects.