# joined table rows into columns with column titles from original rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have three MYSQL tables, simplified, with following columns:

```
ModuleEntries (MDE_ID)
ModuleFields (MDF_ID, MDF_Label)
ModuleEntryFieldValues (MFV_ID, MFV_MDE_ID, MFV_MDF_ID, MFV_Value)
```

As you can see from the simplified column list, `ModuleEntryFieldValues` is the table which states that "for an entry, this field has this value".

Now, I would like to retrieve this information in one "flat" recordset. I have managed to get things working, but not entirely to what i want.
With the help of a different SO article, I managed to get the **dynamic, variable amount of columns** to work, by using a cursor.

```
  declare finish int default 0;
  declare fldid int;
  declare str varchar(10000) default 'SELECT *,';
  declare curs cursor for select MDF_ID from ModuleFields group by MDF_ID;
  declare continue handler for not found set finish = 1;
  open curs;
  my_loop:loop
    fetch curs into fldid;
    if finish = 1 then
      leave my_loop;
    end if;
    set str = concat(str, 'max(case when MFV_MDF_ID = ',fldid,' then MFV_Value else null end) as field_',fldid,',');
  end loop;
  close curs;
  set str = substr(str,1,char_length(str)-1);
  set @str = concat(str, ' from ModuleEntries LEFT join ModuleEntryFieldValues ON MDE_ID = MDF_MDE_ID GROUP BY MDE_ID');
  prepare stmt from @str;
  execute stmt;
  deallocate prepare stmt;
```

What this code **doesn't** do, is allow me to put the column values of `MDF_Label` as the actual column headers of the rows. Now, the above code gives me "field_1, field_2, ..." 

Is it possible to join these three tables, and have the `MDF_Label` as column header for the rows that are now columns in the joined table ?
**I want this...**

```
ModuleEntries  |   ModuleFields         |   ModuleEntryFieldValues
-------------  |   ------------------   |   -----------------------------------
MDE_ID         |   MDF_ID - MDF_Label   |   MFV_MDE_ID - MFV_MDF_ID - MFV_Value
1              |   1      - Height      |   1          - 1          - 120cms
               |   2      - Width       |   1          - 2          - 30cms
               |   3      - Weight      |
```

**into this**

```
Recordset
---------
MDE_ID - Height - Width - Weight
1      - 120cms - 30cms - null
```

I hope my question was clear enough. If not please comment and I will give more information where needed, if I can.

Comment: Take a look at the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985842/mysql-concat-to-create-column-names. I am sensing it might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) instead of cursors to generate the prepared statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
 ' SELECT MDE_ID,'

,  GROUP_CONCAT(
     't', MDF_ID, '.MFV_Value AS `', REPLACE(MDF_Label, '`', '``'), '`'
   )

,' FROM ModuleEntries '

, GROUP_CONCAT(
    'LEFT JOIN ModuleEntryFieldValues AS t', MDF_ID, '
       ON t', MDF_ID, '.MFV_MDE_ID = ModuleEntries.MDE_ID
      AND t', MDF_ID, '.MFV_MDF_ID = ', MDF_ID
  SEPARATOR ' ')

) INTO @qry FROM ModuleFields;
```

Save for whitespace editing to make it more readable, with your sample data `@qry` would then contain:

```
SELECT MDE_ID,
       t1.MFV_Value AS `Height`,
       t2.MFV_Value AS `Width`,
       t3.MFV_Value AS `Weight`
FROM   ModuleEntries
  LEFT JOIN ModuleEntryFieldValues AS t1
         ON t1.MFV_MDE_ID = ModuleEntries.MDE_ID AND t1.MFV_MDF_ID = 1
  LEFT JOIN ModuleEntryFieldValues AS t2
         ON t2.MFV_MDE_ID = ModuleEntries.MDE_ID AND t2.MFV_MDF_ID = 2
  LEFT JOIN ModuleEntryFieldValues AS t3
         ON t3.MFV_MDE_ID = ModuleEntries.MDE_ID AND t3.MFV_MDF_ID = 3
```

One can then prepare and execute that statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET @qry = NULL;
```

Which yields the following results:

```
MDE_ID    Height    Width    Weight
     1    120cms    30cms    (null)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b840b/10).

Comment: I am getting an error when there are no records in the tables. Is there a way to overcome this? `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1`

Comment: @UwConcept: Move the comma after `MDE_ID` into the `GROUP_CONCAT` and define `SEPARATOR ''`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I still got an error. The problem was that if there were no ModuleFields at all, the variable `@qry` was null. I added a simple check on that variable's value, and only execute the prepared statement when `@qry is not null`. I marked this as answer for your elegant solution and great assistance.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable. The syntax to change the value of `group_concat_max_len` at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:
`SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;` For more info see [MySQL Reference - Group Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)