# recordset.sort invalid row handle

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a MySQL stored procedure generating a resultset. The query uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to select rows as columns.

**SQL Code snippet**

```
SELECT CONCAT(
 ' SELECT MDE_ID, MDE_CreatedOn, MDE_LastEditedOn '

,  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
   ' ,t', MDF_ID, '.MDEMDF_Value AS `', REPLACE(MDF_Label, '`', '``'), '`'
   ) SEPARATOR ' ')
```

Following, I want to sort the recordset on a column.

```
SQL = "CALL moduleentry_select(" & prjid & ",0,26,0)"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorLocation = 3
rs.LockType = 3
rs.Open SQL, Conn
rs.Sort = "volgnummer"
```

I have verified and the column is in the recordset.

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft Cursor Engine error '80040e04'
Row handle is invalid.
default.asp, line 176
```

Line 176 is `rs.Sort = "volgnummer"`

**edit**

The column 'Volgnummer' doesn't actually exist in the database. It is selected dynamically via a pivoting principle, using `GROUP_CONCAT`. Referring to this SA answer: [joined table rows into columns with column titles from original rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677700/joined-table-rows-into-columns-with-column-titles-from-original-rows)

Comment: I have you verified the column exists in the recordset?

Comment: Have you read my question completely? ;)

Comment: Sorry, meant to write "**How** have you verified the column exists in the recordset", blonde moment :/

Comment: Ahh, no problem :) I ran the stored procedure call in MySQL Workbench and saw the column in the resultset.

Comment: Oh, that's far from meaning the column exists in the **classic ASP recordset** then. If you just remove the `rs.Sort` line, what do you get? I suspect you'll get empty recordset or unexpected columns.

Comment: It works fine without the sort, **and** it works fine when I sort on column `MDE_ID` which wasn't created with `GROUP_CONCAT`, **and** I can print the value in the recordset by `<%=rs("volgnummer")%>`.

Comment: Hmm... last one before I'm out of ideas: what is the type of "volgnummer" column? Is it different from the type of "MDE_ID"?

Comment: The resultset was created using the answer in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677700/joined-table-rows-into-columns-with-column-titles-from-original-rows . I believe it is either a `MEDIUMTEXT`, or `BLOB`

Comment: So maybe ADO can't handle that type when sorting... can you convert the type to something more common?

Comment: I am not sure I will be able to convert the column, but I can try to convert or cast the datatype in the query. I'll keep in touch when changed. Thx

Comment: It is a `MEDIUMTEXT` column, but I cannot change the type, nor cast it to a different type as the data length requires `MEDIUMTEXT`.

Comment: If you store the value of `<%=rs("volgnummer")%>` in local variable, then call `rs.MoveNext` then compare the values does it work?