# mysql create view from working "prepare" statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT `table`.id', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     ,    `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`.value
         AS `', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`'
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM `table` ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN `table`   AS `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`
            ON `table`.id = `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`.id
           AND `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`.name = ', QUOTE(name)
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY `table`.id'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM `table`) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

from [this question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value) Honestly, I barely understand it, I'm surprised it is even possible, but after modifying some names it does exactly what I need, but I need it in a "View".

How would I add this to a view in my database?

Many Thanks

Comment: there is no way to make view from dynamic sql statement. but you can create `create view ...`  statement and execute it whenever content of table that affects on column count changed

Comment: This is true, I could do this. I could dynamically create the sql [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,75357,75632#msg-75632) but it uses "max()" to aggregate/group but preferably I'd have a function that can handle text. Though, I could work around that too. Something like: useTheOneThatIsntNull() heh

Found it! group_concat, gotta get rid of seperator, which I think I can do.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's a while this question was asked, but I know this is possible.

A little modification to the last section of your prepared query as shown below will help you achieve your aim:

**Just modify before the `PREPARE stmt`**

```
SET @qrys = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "put_your_view_name_without_quote" AS ',@qry);
PREPARE stmt FROM @qrys;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: This will work only if you omit the two side quotations of the view name.