# mysql - performing addition, subtraction etc on two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following Mysql table storing meter readings of different power stations.

```
Date, station_name, reading
2013-05-06, ABC, 102
2013-05-06, PQR, 122
```

I want a SQL query with following result for a particular date.

```
Date, ABC, PQR, ABC-PQR
2013-05-06,102,122,-20
```

Comment: Please show what you tried!

Comment: What if there is more than 2 stations?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CASE statements:

```
SELECT Date
      , SUM(CASE WHEN station_name = 'ABC' THEN reading ELSE 0 END) as ABC
      , SUM(CASE WHEN station_name = 'PQR' THEN reading ELSE 0 END) as PQR
      , SUM(CASE WHEN station_name = 'ABC' THEN reading ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN station_name = 'PQR' THEN reading ELSE 0 END) as 'ABC-PQR'
FROM table
WHERE Date = '20130506'
GROUP BY Date
```

You can search for MySQL PIVOT to find out other methods people use.

Comment: I believe he want dynamic column, not separated by comma

Comment: @invisal . . . It is entirely unclear.  If the OP wants it as a comma separated string, then it is easy enough to use `concat()` or `concat_ws()` to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is not possible to do dynamic column based on value of row. I believe you should do it in application-layer rather than database-layer.

See this post: [mysql select dynamic row values as column names, another column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value).