# Dynamic rows to columns from multiple tables with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, dynamic, group-concat

So I've been reading through some of the other questions about dynamic rows to columns. By adapting another query in another answer here
[mysql select dynamic row values as column names, another column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value),
I can get it to work for a single table, however I need to also pull records from two other tables to include in the result. Given these tables:

```
Cars
ID    BRAND    NAME   etc1...
1     gmc      sierra
2     ford     ranger
3     dodge    dakota
4     kia      rio

Dice
ID    DESCRIPTION
1     blue
2     green
3     red
etc2. etc2.

Stock
ID    CAR_ID    DICE_ID    NUMBER
1     1         3          01V,3Y6
2     3         1          8Z4
3     2         2          03X
4     1         1          C7B
```

So yes this doesn't make much sense but it's only to show the structure. My result needs to come out looking like this:

```
CAR_ID    BRAND    NAME    etc1.    BLUE    GREEN    RED     etc2.
1         gmc      sierra  ...     C7B     null     01V,3Y6 ...
2         ford     ranger  ...     null    03X      null    ...
3         dodge    dakota  ...     8Z4     null     null    ...
4         kia      rio     ...     null    null     null    ...
```

Simple if it was static but the number of rows in Cars and Dice will be dynamic so it can't be hard-coded. I can get Dice to output the rows into columns but there are two things I can't figure out:

- The main query is supposed to list all columns from the Cars table along with all rows as columns from the Dice table but I can't figure out how to attach the Dice query to the Cars query.
- I need to pull the relative description from the Dice table to use as a column header. Using dice.id is not practical or helpful. I can't figure out how to incorporate this into my working query for the Dice table.

Does anyone know how to produce the desired results?

**Edit 1:** I forgot to say that the results must list ALL Cars whether or not they have Dice in stock.

**Edit 2:** I should have clarified that NUMBER meant product number and not count. This is a string field that can hold multiple product numbers. It's legacy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(D.ID = ',D.ID,', D.ID, NULL)) as \'', D.DESCRIPTION, '\'')) INTO @sql FROM Dice D;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT C.*, ', @sql, ' FROM Cars C INNER JOIN Stock S ON C.Id = S.Car_Id  INNER JOIN Dice D ON S.DICE_ID = D.ID GROUP BY C.ID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:  #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Comment: Removing the DEALLOCATE command fixed it. See my edit 1 and edit 2 for clarification. Also, thanks for your help.