# Can I build semi-advanced reports using only MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table whose structure and data looks something like this:

```
name |       date | type  | value
-----+------------+-------+------
foo  | 2013-01-01 | blue  |     4
foo  | 2013-01-02 | green |     1
foo  | 2013-01-01 | blue  |     9
foo  | 2013-01-02 | green |     5
bar  | 2013-01-01 | blue  |    10
bar  | 2013-01-02 | green |     4
bar  | 2013-01-01 | blue  |     6
bar  | 2013-01-02 | green |     2
meow | 2013-01-01 | blue  |     5
meow | 2013-01-02 | green |     6
meow | 2013-01-01 | blue  |     4
meow | 2013-01-02 | green |     4
```

I'm trying to construct a query that will produce this output:

```
name | blue | green
-----+------+------
foo  |   13 |     6
bar  |   16 |     6
meow |    9 |    10
```

The `name` column is maintained. The `blue` and `green` columns of the output are generated based on the values of the `type` table column. The values of those two columns are the accumulated value of the `value` table column for all `date`s. I hope that made sense.

This is a bit out of my league when it comes to MySQL so I have no idea where to start. Is this possible using MySQL, and if so, how? For instance, how does one create output columns based on the values of a single table column?

---

***Edit:*** I should specify; there is no need for this to be a single query. As long as it can be done without involving any other technologies than MySQL then I have no constraints regarding subqueries, multiple queries, views etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` and `SUM()` if you have known number of values.

```
SELECT  Name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'blue' THEN value ELSE 0 END) blue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'green' THEN value ELSE 0 END) green
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9643b/1)

But if you have unknown number of values, you can build a dynamic query for that which yield the same result as with static query,

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN type = ''',
               type,
               ''' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`', type, '`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM TableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM    tableName
                    GROUP   BY Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9643b/3)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `SUM` with `GROUP BY` should solve it for you;

```
SELECT name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type='blue' THEN value ELSE 0 END) blue,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type='green' THEN value ELSE 0 END) green
FROM Table1
GROUP BY name;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40981/2).

...or using somewhat briefer MySQL specific code;

```
SELECT name, 
  SUM(IF(type='blue', value, 0)) blue,
  SUM(IF(type='green', value, 0)) green
FROM Table1
GROUP BY name;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40981/7).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'blue' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS blue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'green' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS green
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
```

There's no `PIVOT` function in MySQL like there is in SQL Server for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The output format is making this (unneccessary?) hard for you. A query that would give an output like this:

```
name | color | amount
```

which in your code you could easily rewrite to

```
name | blue | green
```

would that work for you?

```
SELECT name, color, sum(value) as amount
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name, color
```

Comment: That's the whole point of the question, IMHO. "build semi-advanced reports"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT name, sum(CASE type WHEN 'blue' THEN value END) blue,
             sum(CASE type WHEN 'green' THEN value END) green FROM tbl
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible in a single SQL statement from within MySQL. What you can do is create a "meta-query" which generates an sql statement which you can then prepare and execute.

Have a look at, e.g., [mysql select dynamic row values as column names, another column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value)

Comment: There's no need for this to be a single statement. Check the updated question.