# Mysql Variable in PDO Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I found the answer for my problem from this [mysql select dynamic row values as column names, another column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value). Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT dm_generics.dm_id', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     ,    t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '.field_value
         AS ', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), ''
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM dm_generics ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN dm_generics   AS t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '
            ON dm_generics.dm_id = t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '.dm_id
           AND t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '.field_name = ', QUOTE(field_name)
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY dm_generics.dm_id'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM dm_generics) t;
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

But, I was confused how to execute that query inside the PDO.

I had tried to use something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute())
{
    $object = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $object;
}
```

Instead of using PDO::prepare, I also tried to use PDO query

```
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
```

But, I got an empty array or null. I guess there was something 'wrong' with the query, maybe because there's a MySQL variable inside?

Here's the fiddle provided by the answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e689/1

So, could you please tell me what the problem is and how to make it work?

**UPDATE:**

As [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) suggestion, now i can make those query worked. Here's the code:

```
$sql    = "SELECT CONCAT(
'SELECT dm_generics.dm_id', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     ,    t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '.field_value
         AS ', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), ''
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM dm_generics ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN dm_generics   AS t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '
            ON dm_generics.dm_id = t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '.dm_id
           AND t_', REPLACE(field_name, '', ''), '.field_name = ', QUOTE(field_name)
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY dm_generics.dm_id'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM dm_generics) t;";
$sql2   = "PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;";
$sql3   = "EXECUTE stmt;";

$stmt   = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt2  = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
$stmt3  = $dbh->prepare($sql3);

if($stmt->execute() && $stmt2->execute() && $stmt3->execute())
{
     return $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Comment: run each query in separate call

Comment: Ouch, this is embarrasing.. thanks for your suggestion, now it worked.

Comment: why you are using prepare when not a single placeholder is used?

Comment: I'll add some additional query (WHERE statement) to the existing query. :)

Comment: Btw, I had one more problem, based on the updated code above, i add WHERE statement into the $sql1 then add $stmt->bindValue(':aaa', $aaa); but i can't get it work :(. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, nothing printed any error messages..
The PHP file http://pastebin.com/QDN22t7S

Comment: sorry, I've my own code to debug at hand.