# Select dynamic row values as column names, in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql

In continuation with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410946/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names/25411480): I have to use dynamic row values as columns but the order of the columns needs to be specific. If you look at the following example, I have to order the selected columns by start_time in the ascending order.

E.g.:

```
+---------+------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| exec_id | project_id | flow_id           | job_id   | start_time    | end_time      |
+---------+------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
|   10919 |         16 | my_flow_cleanup   | init     | 10            | 15            |
|   10919 |         16 | my_flow_cleanup   | job_id_1 | 30            | 40            |
|   10919 |         16 | my_flow_cleanup   | job_id_2 | 40            | 50            |
|   10919 |         16 | my_flow_cleanup   | job_id_3 | 20            | 25            |
+---------+------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

From the previous question:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN job_id = ''',
         job_id, 
         ''' THEN start_time END) `',
         job_id,
         '_start`',
         ',',
         'MAX(CASE WHEN job_id = ''',
         job_id,
         ''' THEN end_time END) `',
         job_id,
         '_end`' 
         )

 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT exec_id, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM t 
                    GROUP BY exec_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Above query will return following result:

```
exec_id     init_start            init_end            job_id_1_start       job_id_1_end       job_id_2_start        job_id_2_end        job_id_3_start      job_id_3_end
10919       10                    15                  30                   40                 40                    50                  20                  25
```

But I need:

```
exec_id     init_start            init_end            job_id_3_start       job_id_3_end       job_id_1_start        job_id_1_end        job_id_2_start      job_id_2_end
10919       10                    15                  20                   25                 30                    40                  40                  50
```

Please notice that the order of columns is now changed, according to start_time.

I tried to do this with `temporary tables` and `views`, I thought it would be very easy. Unfortunately, I don't have create table/create view permissions. Is there a way to achieve this without temp table and views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding `ORDER BY start_time ASC` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN job_id = ''',
         job_id, 
         ''' THEN start_time END) `',
         job_id,
         '_start`',
         ',',
         'MAX(CASE WHEN job_id = ''',
         job_id,
         ''' THEN end_time END) `',
         job_id,
         '_end`' 
         )
          ORDER BY start_time ASC        
 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT exec_id, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM t 
                    GROUP BY exec_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d01d12/1)