# how to select dynamic columns which are result of another query in mySQl

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have two tables. 
First table have column called column_name which contains values columns names of the second table like ( column1 , column2 , etc).
I need to select columns from the second table depending on the result of query column_name from the first table .

I need help solving this issue but I cant develop it:

[image]

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Please considered that questions like "how to do it?" are considered off-topic here; you should add something about what you tried so far, the problems you are having, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql select dynamic row values as column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410946/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names)

Comment: image added with what i need in details please help

Answer (score 0):

If You work with Oracle, i suggest You to use listagg function (http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515)

And Query will be like:

```
Select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = name_of_your_table2 and column_name in (select listagg...)
```

if I understand correctly.

Comment: I didn't refresh tags. My mistake

Comment: The question was never edited and MySQL can be found in the title as well.