# Creating MYSQL column (Alias) based on the value of that column

Tags: mysql, group-by, substring, column-alias

I have the following tables

```
Products, Prices, stores (Suppliers) and Country
```

Products table:

```
ProductID, ProductName
```

Stores Table:

```
StoreID, StoreName, Country (country name of the supplier)
```

Price Table:

```
PriceID, Date, Price, StoreID, ProductID
```

Country Table

```
CountryID, StoreID, CountryName
```

Sample Price Table Data (ID, Date, Price, StoreID, ProductID)

```
1, 01-10-2014, 1500, 1, 8
2, 01-10-2014, 1800, 2, 9
3, 10-10-2014, 1700, 2, 8
4, 01-09-2014, 1200, 1, 8
5, 07-09-2014, 1300, 2, 8
```

In Stores Table

```
1, Supplier1, UAE
2, Supplier2, GB
```

In Product Table

```
8, iPad Air 32GB 4G
9, iPad Air WiFi 16GB
```

Now i need to create a line based chart. There will be two lines on the chart. To create the two lines i need two columns from this table - the UAE and UK

So my expected result is

```
ID Date        UAEPrice  UKSupplier SupplierName
1 01-10-2014  1500       Null       Supplier-1
2 01-10-2014  NULL       1800       Supplier-2
3 10-10-2014  NULL       1700       Supplier-2
4 01-09-2014  1200       Null       Supplier-1
5 07-09-2014 Null        1300       Supplier-1
```

I am confused with this... Currently I am trying with two Table View (one with `stores.countryID = 'AE'` and one with `stores.CountryID <> 'AE'`).

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your current query?

Comment: I got some similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value 

I think we should use GROUP_CONCAT()
anyone can answer with GROUP_CONCAT() ?

Comment: I almost done... If i ca show the Date one the result then i will get a result... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aced91/2

Comment: So is the question how to input the date column? You seem to have answered your own question for how to input a column alias.

Comment: yes... I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value thanks all...