# How to write a MySQL query that will transpose particular row values into new columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Here is the desired result:

```
sr no. | fullname      | email  
----------------------------------------
1.     | demo user     | demo@test.com 
2.     | sagar panchal | sagar@gmail.com
```

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ds_tbl_event_question` q
LEFT JOIN `ds_tbl_event_participant` p ON q.event_id = p.event_id
AND p.question_id = q.event_question_id
LEFT JOIN `ds_events` e ON e.event_id = q.event_id
WHERE (
q.field_type = 'email'
OR q.field_type = 'full_name'
)
AND e.store_code = 'H9OCEN'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This gave output as shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing that would tie the answers together, so it is not possible to achieve what you want. You would need to store who answered the questions, then it would be possible.

Comment: @Shadow, all the fields are not fixed, its dynamic generating

Comment: No idea what you mean by your comment and how it is relevant

Comment: @Shadow, actually for all the forms, fullnames and emails are not compulsory and also not fixed, so its not possible to take fix columns, its depends upon user to add fields ex. fullname, email or phone

Comment: I never said you need to add them as fixed columns.

Comment: @Shadow, it is possible using union ?

Comment: Please could you tell me what is in `ds_tbl_event_participant`? Or expand the screenshot so it shows all the columns returned?

Comment: An interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10925445/2298301. However, for it to work in your case - as indicated in the comments above - there's a need of having a column like `submit_id` or `user_id`, etc. for each _set_ of answers submitted in one go. Eventually, that field will be used to pivot the table data.

Comment: What input do you have?  (Hard to guess from the 'desired result').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if only field `created_date` ties together the records from which you want to take `full_name` and `email`. Given that, you could group by this `created_date` and use an aggregate function (e.g. `min`) considering only the `answer`-values of those records with a particular `field_type`-value:

```
select
  min(CASE field_type WHEN 'full_name' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) as 'fullname',
  min(CASE field_type WHEN 'email' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) as 'email'   
FROM `ds_tbl_event_question` q
     LEFT JOIN `ds_tbl_event_participant` p ON q.event_id = p.event_id AND p.question_id = q.event_question_id
     LEFT JOIN `ds_events` e ON e.event_id = q.event_id
WHERE (
      q.field_type = 'email'
   OR q.field_type = 'full_name'
   )
   AND e.store_code = 'H9OCEN'
group by created_date
```

Note that the aggregate function (here: `min`) is necessary because a select-clause must not contain other attributes than those listed in a group by clause except when used in an aggregate function.

In above query I tried to adapt your query as little as possible. Actually the query could be further shortened: The left joins actually turn into a join as you use a `WHERE`-condition on left hand side values; and the condition on the `field_type` is superfluous as the `case`-statements do not consider any other values at all:

```
select
  min(CASE field_type WHEN 'full_name' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) as 'fullname',
  min(CASE field_type WHEN 'email' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) as 'email'   
FROM `ds_tbl_event_question` q
     JOIN `ds_tbl_event_participant` p ON q.event_id = p.event_id AND p.question_id = q.event_question_id
     JOIN `ds_events` e ON e.event_id = q.event_id AND e.store_code = 'H9OCEN'
group by created_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT full_names.answer AS full_name,
       emails.answer AS email FROM
(SELECT created_date
 FROM ds_tbl_event_question
 GROUP BY created_date) created_dates
JOIN 
(SELECT created_date, answer
 FROM ds_tbl_event_question
 WHERE field_type = 'full_name') full_names
ON full_names.created_date = created_dates.created_date
JOIN 
(SELECT created_date, answer
 FROM ds_tbl_event_question
 WHERE field_type = 'email') emails
ON emails.created_date = created_dates.created_date
```

See Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OBQ69221

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the only way to associate is with created date:

Select q.answer as fullname, 
      (select answer from ds_tbl_event_question where field_type = 'email' and created_date = q.created_date) as email
from ds_tbl_event_question q where q.field_type = 'full_name';