# Union two query result column-wise

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say if I have two queries returning two tables with the same number of rows.
For example, if query 1 returns

```
| a | b | c |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

and query 2 returns

```
| d  | e  | f  |
| 7  | 8  | 9  |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
```

How to obtain the following, assuming both queries are opaque

```
| a | b | c | d  | e  | f  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 7  | 8  | 9  |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
```

My current solution is to add to each query a row number column and inner join them
on this column.

```sql
SELECT
    q1_with_rownum.*,
    q2_with_rownum.*
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS q1_rownum, q1.*
    FROM (.......) q1
) q1_with_rownum
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS q2_rownum, q2.*
    FROM (.......) q2
) q2_with_rownum
ON q1_rownum = q2_rownum
```

However, if there is a column named `q1_rownum` in either of the query,
the above will break. It is not possible for me to look into `q1` or `q2`;
the only information available is that they are both valid SQL queries
and do not contain columns with same names. Are there any SQL construct
similar to `UNION` but for columns instead of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function.  A *row* in a table is an entity.

If you are constructing generic code to run on any tables, you can try using less common values, such as `"an unusual query rownum"` -- or something more esoteric than that.  I would suggest using the same name in both tables and then using `using` clause for the `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your exact problem, but I think you mean both q1 and q2 are joined on a column with the same name?

You should add each table name before the column to distinguish which column is referenced:
`"table1"."similarColumnName" = "table2"."similarColumnName"`

EDIT:
So, problem is that if there is already a column with the same alias as your ROW_NUMBER(), the JOIN cannot be made because you have an ambiguous column name.

The easier solution if you cannot know your incoming table's columns is to make a solid alias, for example `_query_join_row_number`

EDIT2:
You could look into prefixing all columns with their original table's name, thus removing any conflict (you get q1_with_rows.rows and conflict column is q1_with_rows.q1.rows)
an example stack on this: [In a join, how to prefix all column names with the table it came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153344/in-a-join-how-to-prefix-all-column-names-with-the-table-it-came-from)

Comment: Also, make sure your rows are matching where you want with an ORDER BY, if there is no id to either query. If there is meaning to each row like "client1" and "client2" who should have their own results to column "a" and "f" not mixed up

Comment: I am not able to look into either of the query because they are user-inputted SQL strings, so I don't know what columns "table1" actually has... If "table1" already have a column called "rownum" it will clash with my `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum`

Comment: Cannot believe I forgot, but Gordon Linoff hit it right. `USING (column)` is a shortcut for `ON table1.column = table2.column`.

Comment: Ah, your question is not related to the JOIN then, but whether the alias can be used. I think the default  name generated is `row_number` anyway, just use that?

Comment: Basically, I have two tables with equal number of rows (and all distinct column names). I want to make a third table containing columns from both tables. It is not possible for me to know what columns each table actually have so no `SELECT q1.col_1, q1.col_2` etc.

Comment: other than constructing a solid alias to avoid ambiguous conflict, I don't think there is any way to make a "use first column" in SQL. something like query_join_row_number should be solid enough, no?